# Understanding Summation sequence

Tags: summation

I'm trying to wrap my head around this summation. I understand basic ones for the most part, stop, start, etc, but I don't understand this one in particular.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The summation starts from 0 and ends with n.

It is equal to $x^0+x^1+x^2+....+x^n$

$\implies 1+x^1+x^3+....+x^n$

which is nothing but finite geometric series whose summation can be given by

$\frac {a(1-x^{n+1})}{1-x}$ where $a=1$ the first term of the series

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$x^{n+1} - 1 = (x -1)(1 + x + ... + x^n) \Rightarrow \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1} = 1 + x + ... x^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k $$

Which can be easily shown by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k.$$
Then, we have
$$xS=\color{red}{x^1+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}+x^n}+x^{n+1}$$
$$S=x^0+\color{red}{x^1+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}+x^n}.$$
Subtracting the latter from the former gives us
$$xS-S=x^{n+1}-x^0.$$
Hence, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k=S=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$
for $x\not=1$.

Comment: why did you subtract xS and S, and how did you come up with xS?

Comment: @ChetSteadman: See the red parts are the same. So, subtracting $S$ from $xS$ gives us a simple result because the red parts are canceled.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, why did you multiply 'x' by S?

Comment: @ChetSteadman: Because we can get $S$ by doing so. Let $A$ be the red part, i.e, $S=x^0+A=1+A$. Then, we have $xS=x+xA=A+x^{n+1}$. So, we have $xS-S=(A+x^{n+1})-(1+A)=x^{n+1}-1.$

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard trick for summing a geometric series. Put
$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n x^i=1+x+\cdots+x^n$$
Then
$$xS_n=x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n+1}$$
Then subtract these two to get
$$\require{cancel}xS_n-S_n=(\cancel{x}+\cancel{x^2}+\cdots+x^{n+1})-(1+\cancel{x}+\cdots+\cancel{x^n})$$
$$(x-1)S_n =x^{n+1}-1$$
and as long as $x\neq 1$, the factor $(x-1)$ is nonzero so we can divide to get
$$S_n =\boxed{\dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}}$$

Note that this holds for any such finite sum, regardless of whether or not the infinite series converges.

In case $x=1$, the sum is simply $$S_n =\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n \textrm{ copies}}= n$$